# Wordpress - Download PDF corrupted with Types plugin

Tags: php, file, pdf, wordpress

I'm using the plugin "Types - Custom Fields and Custom Post Types Management" to customize some pages on my WP project.
On a page I have several posts displayed with a dowload button for each one, that should download the respective PDF file.

The problem is that the download popup is opened, but the PDF file is corrupted after the download. Here's the code of my template:

```
<div class="cpt-indices-box-c">
    <a href="<?php echo(types_render_field("indice-pdf-download", array( 'raw' => 'true', "output" => "pdf-download" ) )); ?>">PDF para Download</a>
</div>
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Your code works for me, though the API (http://wp-types.com/documentation/functions/#file) seems to indicate that your array keys are not valid.  Are you using the latest version of the plugin?  Try getting rid of the 'raw' key so that you have array("output" => "raw").  Both ways work for me.  Does your file open from the Media Library?  When you hover over the link in your browser, do you see a valid URL?

Comment: Yeah, the file is in the Media Library and the URL is ok, a link to a page like "download.php?path-to-file.pdf". I removed the page "download.php" and let the link pointing to the PDF path.
Now the file is shown in the browser. Not what i wanted, but the client is happy.
Thanks @MarkLeiber